# Meteor React render component to div inside main html file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I'm not really sure what is happening when the component tries to find the div, but here is my render and my div.

HTML:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

Render function:

```
Meteor.startup(() => { ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app')); });
```

I get this error in the console: Error: Target container is not a DOM element.

I also put a console.log after my render function trying to find the div id but returned = null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What packages have you got installed?

if you've still got `blaze-html-templates` or `templating`, remove them both and replace with `static-html`

Otherwise Meteor will render the html as a blaze template some time after startup. (Also if you're using React, you probably don't want to ship Blaze to the client as well!)

Comment: The blaze-html-templates was the problem. Thank you

Comment: No problem, you aren't the first to run into this! haha

Answer (score 0):

See http://archive.is/g20il#selection-399.104-399.186

Hard to see without your full html but your script tag to the .js script should be *after* the div id "app" tag.

Comment: Welcome @Yuting, as this question is tagged `Meteor` the load order of scripts is not in the developers control, so your answer doesn't apply in this case. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: Also I can't get the archive page to load. For future reference, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the heads up! The link had is meant to take you to a page with highlighted text, not sure why it only works for me T.T